# pandas .apply args unpacks lists automatically?

Tags: python, pandas

I can't find anything on this in the documentation or on SO yet…

Given:

```
def applied_func(row, list_of_values):
  for val in list_of_values:
    // do something generative
  return generated_thing

list_for_applied_func = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

df['computed value'] = df.apply(applied_func, args=(list_for_applied_func), axis=1))
```

I get the unexpected error "applied_func() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given. This tells me that it is auto-unpacking `list_of_applied_func` in the above. How is one to treat the list passed as an argument as a list for use in the computed function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as [this line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.4/pandas/core/apply.py#L110) shows, the `args` is sent with unpacking i.e. `f(..., *args)`. A remedy is to turn your list into a 1-tuple:

```
                                  # note the comma|
df.apply(applied_func, args=(list_for_applied_func,), axis=1))
```

This way `args` will be a 1-tuple and when `*`'ed, a list will be passed.

Comment: Ah, the comma that makes all the difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you do `(list_for_applied_func)`, you are simply passing `list_for_applied_func`, you need to actually pass a tuple that contains a list, so you can try:

```py
df['computed value'] = df.apply(applied_func, args=(list_for_applied_func,), axis=1))
```

For example, try this

```
>>> isinstance(([3, 4, 5]), tuple)
False
>>> isinstance(([3, 4, 5], ), tuple)
True
```